# Does a weapon thrown with Giantkind Gloves gain weapon benefits?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, class-feature, ranged-attack

[**Giantkind Gloves**](https://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1399) possess the following power:

> **Power**  [image: *]  (Standard Action)
>
> Strength + 2 vs. AC; ranged 6/12; you throw an object 30 lb. or less; 2d6 + Strength modifier damage.
>     *Level 14:* Strength + 4 vs. AC; ranged 8/16; 50 lb. or less; 2d8 + Strength modifier damage.
>     *Level 24:* Strength + 6 vs. AC; ranged 10/20; 80 lb. or less; 2d12 + Strength modifier damage.

Since no standard weapon weighs over 30 lb., every weapon would be eligible for throwing using this power.

**When throwing a weapon with this power, does this attack benefit from other bonuses?**

Essentially, the questions that I think need to be answered are:

- Does throwing a weapon with this power count as making an attack with
  that weapon?

  (e.g. weapon properties, magic weapon)
- Is this considered "throwing a weapon" for the sake of counting as a thrown weapon attack?

  (e.g. class features, other passives)

## References

The following examples are provided as a reference for what I am asking about.

##### **Weapon Proficiency**

This seems pretty straightforward but worth mentioning. Since the attack does not list the `Weapon` keyword, I do not believe it can benefit from weapon proficiency bonuses:

> Proficiency Bonus: Gained from proficiency with a weapon, this bonus applies to attack rolls with that weapon. *An adventurer gains the proficiency bonus only when wielding the weapon and using powers that have the `weapon` keyword.*

##### **Class Features**

The Seeker's [Spiritbond](https://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=472)  class feature grants two different bonuses to thrown weapon attacks:

> You also gain a *+1 bonus to attack rolls* with both light thrown and heavy thrown weapons, and when you make an attack by throwing a weapon with which you have proficiency, the *weapon returns to your hand after the attack*.

##### **Magic Weapon Returning**

Would throwing a magic weapon with these gauntlets benefit from the rule that states magic weapons return? The power says `ranged 6/12`, which I am guessing makes it a `Ranged` attack- otherwise one would argue it does not provoke opportunity attacks.

> Any magic light thrown or heavy thrown weapon, from the lowly +1 Dagger to the +6 Dragonslayer Javelin automatically returns to the wielder's hand after a Ranged Attack with the weapon is resolved.

##### **Magic Weapon Properties**

For example, when throwing a [Weapon of Long Range](https://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3148), which has the following properties:

> [image: *]  This weapon’s long range increases by 10 squares.
> [image: *]  You do not take the penalty to attack rolls for attacking at long range with this weapon.

It seems the power would not benefit from the first property, but might with the second.

##### **Feats**

- [**Power Throw**](https://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2610) allows you to deal extra damage for a -2 penalty to attack rolls when making a "ranged attack with a heavy thrown weapon".
- [**Arcing Throw**](https://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1888): "When you use a spear as a thrown weapon, the target doesn’t gain cover from its allies."
- [**Brutal Bludgeon**](https://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2483): "When you hit with a club or a mace ... Reroll any damage die result of 1 until the die shows 2 or higher."

##### **Other Passives**

What about other passives, such as the one found on [Dwarven Throwers](https://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1143)?

> Gain a +2 item bonus to thrown weapon damage rolls.

Answer (score 5):

**No, weapons thrown with Giantkind Gloves do not give their usual benefits.**

The Giantkind Gloves attack power does *not* have the `Weapon` keyword, thus no benefits from a weapon you throw apply. As far as the power is concerned, the most powerfully enchanted dagger ever is no better a projectile than a paper airplane would be (and in fact I recommend using paper airplanes with this power, for the entertainment value).

The wording of a few other things deserves a special mention: Power Throw, the returning property of magical weapons, and several other things say, "when you make an attack with this weapon". This is code for "when you use this weapon for an attack with the `weapon` keyword" and does *not* apply in this case.

The only actual exception I can think of is the Seeker's Spiritbond class feature. Because of its phrasing, it probably *will* work when you throw a weapon with Giantkind Gloves.

**And that's a good thing.**

If weapon benefits applied to Giantkind Gloves' attack power, it would be one of the best hand items in the game for strength-based weapon-users. Note that the level 24 version gives a *+6* bonus to attack rolls, which is *enormous* if the power is also getting proficiency and enhancement bonuses to attack rolls. Why use your melee at-wills ever again if you can use Giantkind Gloves to get range, hugely increased accuracy, and ignore your damage die size?

Comment: So you think the second half of Spiritbond would work, not the first?

Comment: @Corion Yes. The first part is an attack bonus on attack rolls *with* thrown weapons (which you're not technically using), but the second part just says "when you make an attack by throwing a weapon".

Comment: Sweet! Now I just need to find a way for my Spiritbond Seeker to gain proficiency with thrown halflings and gnomes at level 24.